# How to convert typeorm json object to raw data

Tags: javascript, nestjs

I have the following JSON Object

```
  {
   "sysUserID":"",
   "personID":1383,
   "xxxx":[
      {
         "sysRoleID":"",
         "institution":{
            "town":{
               "townID":,
               "name":"",
               "municipality":{
               }
            }
         }
      },
      {
         "sysRoleID":0,
         "institution":{
            "town":{
               "name":"",
               "municipality":{
               }
            }
         }
      }
   ],
   "person":{
   }
}
```

I'm using typeorm and this is returned to me. i wish to convert this to Raw Data object. meaning that i want an array from the data even if there is data duplication. Any ideas how i can do this.
I cannot use the typeorm build in function because some other functions im using are not compatible with getRawData()
The nechnologies i am using are JAVASCRIPT AND NESTJS.

Comment: What array would you be looking for? I'm not clear on what you're trying to get back here. Maybe show an output example from what input you've got?

Comment: [
{
   "sysUserID":"",
   "personID":1383,
   " sysRoleID":"",
    "towntownID":,
    "townname":"",
    "townmunicipality":""
   "person":""
},
{
   "sysUserID":"",
   "personID":1383,
   " sysRoleID":"",
    "towntownID":,
    "townname":"",
    "townmunicipality":""
   "person":""
},

]

Comment: So what you need is to "flatten" the object, all the properties must be at the same level, is that correct ?

Comment: Why do we have `towntownID` and not `institutiontowntownID`

Comment: Yes you are correct it should be the full path. I Checked out flatten. it is what i wanted exactly. Thank you